# Why the AnchorLayout is not working properly?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a `boxlayout` which is in the `AnchorLayout` and supposed to be in center, but instead it is located like it is on the picture. I am kinda new to Kivy, so I don't see where the problem lies. I have some suggestions, that I messed up with `AnchorLayout` containing `BoxLayout` or something.

there is my kv code:

```
from kivy.app import  App
import pypyodbc

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import  BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import  AnchorLayout
from kivy.graphics.instructions import  Canvas
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class LoginWidget(Widget):
    pass
class MyLoginScreen(Widget):
    pass

class LoginScreenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLoginScreen()

if __name__=="__main__":
    LoginScreenApp().run()

<LoginWidget>
    BoxLayout:
        spacing:20
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        size:self.parent.width,self.parent.height
        orientation:"vertical"
        Label:
            text:"test"
        Label:
            text:"test"
            font_size:"30sp"
        TextInput:
            multinline:False
            text:"Login"
        TextInput:
            multinline:False
            text:"Password"
        Button:
            text:"register"
            background_normal:""
            size_hint:[1,0.8]
        Button:
            text:"recover password"
            background_normal:""
            size_hint:[1,0.8]
        Button:
            text:"sign in"
            background_color:[.64,.04,.08,1]
            background_normal:""
            size_hint:[1,0.8]
        Label:
            text:"or login through"
<MyLoginScreen>
    AnchorLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        size:root.width*0.4,root.height*0.4
        anchor_x:"center"
        anchor_y:"center"
        LoginWidget:
            size:self.parent.size
```

And this is the window:

[image: here]

Comment: Sorry,i meant that it is located like it is shown on the picture

Comment: Your AnchorLayout has size (100, 100) because you never set anything else. Make MyLoginScreen inherit from BoxLayout, or some other layout that will automatically resize its children.

Comment: but i set size:root.width*0.4,root.height*0.4 in the AnchorLayout, or is it something else?

Comment: In that case, isn't what you see exactly what you expect? You set its size but not its pos, so it has the default pos of (0, 0).

Comment: Your `LoginWidget` is centered within the `AnchorLayout`. The problem is your positioning of the `AnchorLayout` itself. The `anchor_x` and `anchor_y` refer to the positioning of `LoginWidget` within the `AnchorLayout`, not to the positioning of the `AnchorLayout`.